# Is a non reflective display possible?

Tags: optics

Can you think of a surface, that emits light, but doesn't reflect any light coming from outside (absorbs it)? Under what circumstances would this work?

Comment: An event horizon? :) There do exist anti-glare displays already on the market ([e.g.](http://www.perfectfittech.com/blogs/news/6913634-ultra-clear-vs-anti-glare-screen-protector-screen-shield)).

Comment: @lemon yeah, almost forgot an event horizon is an instance of a black body...

Answer (score 3):

That's the definition of a black body. 100% absorptivity implies 0% reflectivity and an emissivity of 1.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: The fundamental problem with this as an answer is that we don't have any trouble defining things that can't be. Indeed most of first year physics is built on the assumption of objects which have properties that we know no real object can actually have (consider all the massless inextensible strings and the frictionless pulleys and the rigid semi-infinite rods).

Comment: @JohnRennie - I disagree with your assessment of this answer. This exactly answers the question: a perfect black body has zero reflectivity yet emits light. Of course the real answer to the question is "yes" but that is too short to be valid. Also, a little more description might be helpful (e.g. "how does a black body emit light" - _see Planck's Law_; and "under what circumstances does this work" - _when it is hot_)

Comment: @Floris: no it doesn't. It just changes the question to *is a perfect black body possible*.

Comment: @JohnRennie I see - you are focused on the question in the title. I read the body of the question ("Can you think of...")